# Get the list of all products having Advanced Pricing, especially Customer Group Pricing in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, tierprice

I want to get a list of all the products that have Customer Group Pricing which have **Website** as **All Website**

[image: All Websites]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all product which has tier price by below code

```
$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
productCollection = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory')->create();
     foreach ($productCollection as $value) {
        $productId = $value->getEntityId();
        $obj->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
        $product_obj = $product->load($productId);
        $tier_price_obj = $product_obj->getTierPrices();
        if (count($tier_price_obj) > 0) {
            $arrayTierProducts[] = $productId;
        }
     }
```

$arrayTierProducts is the array of product id which has tier price.

**You should not use the ObjectManager directly!**

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It would be helpful if you helped me to get the tier prices associated with specific website ID say 0 or 1.

Comment: Also, I am going to delete the Customer Group Price entries of the said website ID. So can it be done via a MySQL command or do I have to do it via PHP script itself?